# Android: start animation from state it ends

Tags: android, animation, rotation

So i got this Rotation Animation:

```
rotate = new RotateAnimation(0f, -270f,200,200);
rotate.setDuration(2000);
rotate.setFillAfter(true);
```

and i have Button that start the animation on click

```
public void click(View view){
Image.startAnimation(rotate);
}
```

and when i click on button animation starts correctly and ends on needed state. but when i click second time it begin from state it was before any animation.

Question:
 how can i start animation from the state it ends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object Animator instead

```
ObjectAnimator imageViewObjectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageview ,
                "rotation", 0f, -270f);
        imageViewObjectAnimator.setDuration(2000);
        imageViewObjectAnimator.start();
```

Comment: well not exactly what i want, but i can adjust this to my need and it will work, i  already test it)) Thanks.

Comment: the trick is that this "ObjectAnimator.ofFloat" always start from one position and go to another and if i remember previous position i can make it start from it

Comment: Ya just store a global variable for the last starting position